# Why does my Properties object ignore the defaults when I do a get?

Tags: java

```
Properties defaults = new Properties();
defaults.put("color", "black");

Properties props = new Properties(defaults);

// This prints "null, black"
System.out.println(props.get("color") + ", " + props.getProperty(color));
```

Comment: What is the "color" variable here?

Comment: Wait, someone is asking already answered questions from Peter Norvigs IAQ here xX Not exactly sure why anyone would want to do this..  [link](http://www.norvig.com/java-iaq.html)

Comment: @Voo, even the questions haven't been reworded. I don't think Norvig has given a bad explanation at all.

Comment: @Vineet I agree. A mod should probably look into that, but actually I'm way too curious WHAT actually is going on here to get that user banned or something ;)

Answer (score 5):

Java made the unfortunate decision of making `Properties` *subclass* `Hashtable` instead of merely *containing* a `Hashtable`.

The `getProperty` method uses the default backing `Properties`, but the `get` method inherited from `Hashtable` doesn't. So if you write:

```
System.out.println(props.getProperty("color"));
```

it will print "black" as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

```
get public V get(Object key)
```

method inherited from HashMap.
Returns the value to which the specified key is mapped, or null if this map contains no mapping for the key.

When you use constructor new Property(default) you set internal field *default* to your default properties. When you use getProperty Properties class lookup in *default* property and return value from it if Properties HashMap doesn't contain value.

```
public String getProperty(String key) {
   Object oval = super.get(key);
   String sval = (oval instanceof String) ? (String)oval : null;
return ((sval == null) && (defaults != null)) ? defaults.getProperty(key) : sval;
}
```